# direct product decompositions of semi-rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, semiring

(With Hilbert's Basis Theorem in mind.)

Is it true that every finitely presented commutative semi-ring with unit is a finite direct product of directly indecomposable factors?

Comment: How do you define a finitely *presented* semiring?

Comment: @rschwieb: A semiring is f.p. if it is the quotient of a finitely generated free semiring by a finitely generated congruence. Maybe `finitely presentable' is better? Anyway, it should be correct analogue of the ring case.

Comment: How nice is the theory of idempotents for semirings?  It looks like the main character $1-e$ gets dealt a blow since we don't have additive inverses...

Comment: @rschwieb A pair of elements $x, y$ such that ${x + y = 1}$ and ${x y = 0}$ certainly determines a direct product decomposition. But I think more is required to answer the question. And I would have guessed that the answer is known, but I have not found it in the web.